# GSSException: Message stream modified (41)

Tags: java, security, kerberos, ntlm, gssapi

I'm working with an LDAP in forest architecture (all servers and my server are windows). I'm binding to the AD using NTLM authentication.

I have a Java code that perform the operations against the LDAP server.

The code is wrapped as a tomcat servlet.

When running the Java code directly (just executing the LDAP authentication code as an application), the bind works both against the local domain (local domain = I logged in to windows, and ran this process with a user of this domain) and foreign domains.

When running the Java code as a servlet, the bind works and authenticates users from one domain but does not work if I'm trying to authenticate users from other domain, it won't work (it will work only if I'll restart tomcat).

I'm getting an exception:

```
GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Message stream modified (41))]]
```

I'll mention that it is the same code, with the same configurations and the same krb5 file.

More information:

This is my code:

```
public void func(String realm, String kdc) {
    try {
      URL configURL = getClass().getResource("jaas_ntlm_configuration.txt");
        System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", configURL.toString());

            System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.realm", realm);
            System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.kdc",kdc);

        // If the application is run on NT rather than Unix, use this name
        String loginAppName = "MyConfig";

        // Create login context
        LoginContext lc = new LoginContext(loginAppName, new SampleCallbackHandler());

        // Retrieve the information on the logged-in user
        lc.login();

        // Get the authenticated subject
        Subject subject = lc.getSubject();

        System.out.println(subject.toString());

        Subject.doAs(subject, new JndiAction(new String[] { "" }));
    }
    catch (LoginException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class JndiAction implements java.security.PrivilegedAction {
    private String[] args;

    public JndiAction(String[] origArgs) {
        this.args = (String[])origArgs.clone();
    }

    public Object run() {
        performJndiOperation(args);
        return null;
    }

    private static void performJndiOperation(String[] args) {

        // Set up environment for creating initial context
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable(11);

        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");

        // Must use fully qualified hostname
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://server:389");

        // Request the use of the "GSSAPI" SASL mechanism
        // Authenticate by using already established Kerberos credentials
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "GSSAPI");

        try {
            // Create the initial context
            DirContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);


            // Close the context when we're done
            ctx.close();
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And my `jaas_ntlm_configuration.txt` file contains:

```
MyConfig { com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
useTicketCache=true
doNotPrompt=false;
};
```

My `krb5.conf` file is:

```
# 
# All rights reserved.
#
#pragma ident   @(#)krb5.conf   1.1 00/12/08

[libdefaults]
    default_tkt_enctypes = des3-cbc-sha1 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc
    default_tgs_enctypes = des3-cbc-sha1 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc
    forwardable  = true
    renewable  = true
    noaddresses = true
    clockskew  = 300

[realms]
        SUB1.EXAMPLE.COM = {
                kdc = DDC.SUB1.EXAMPLE.COM
        default_domain=EXAMPLE.COM
        }
    SUB2.EXAMPLE.COM = {
                kdc = DDC.SUB.EXAMPLE.COM
        default_domain=EXAMPLE.COM
        }
    SUB3.EXAMPLE.COM = {
                kdc = DDC.SUB3.EXAMPLE.COM
        default_domain=EXAMPLE.COM
        }

[domain_realm]
    .EXAMPLE.COM = SUB1.EXAMPLE.COM
    .EXAMPLE.COM = SUB2.EXAMPLE.COM
    .EXAMPLE.COM = SUB3.EXAMPLE.COM

[logging]
        default = FILE:/var/krb5/kdc.log
        kdc = FILE:/var/krb5/kdc.log
    kdc_rotate = {

# How often to rotate kdc.log. Logs will get rotated no more
# often than the period, and less often if the KDC is not used
# frequently.

        period = 1d

# how many versions of kdc.log to keep around (kdc.log.0, kdc.log.1, ...)

        versions = 10
    }

[appdefaults]   
    kinit = {
        renewable = true
        forwardable= true
    }
    rlogin = {
        forwardable= true
    }
    rsh = {
        forwardable= true
    }
    telnet = {
            autologin = true 
        forwardable= true
    }
```

I added the following as Java parameters:

```
-Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false -Djava.security.krb5.conf="krb5.conf" -Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true
```

If I call func("SUB*.EXAMPLE.COM", "DDC.SUB*.EXAMPLE.COM") always with the same subdomain - it will work, but if I'll call with one subdomain and then with another, the second will fail.

**More information:**

Here is the output with krb5.debug=true:

```
java -Xmx100m -cp gssapi_test.jar -Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false -Djava.security.krb5.conf="krb5.conf" -Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true  gssapitest.myTest my_config.txt
2 users provided. Performing authentication #1
Reading configuration file my_config.txt
kdc: DDC.SUB1.EXAMPLE.COM, realm: SUB1.EXAMPLE.COM
>>>KinitOptions cache name is C:\Users\user1\krb5cc_user1
>> Acquire default native Credentials
>>> Obtained TGT from LSA: Credentials:
client=user1@SUB1.EXAMPLE.COM
server=krbtgt/SUB1.EXAMPLE.COM@SUB1.EXAMPLE.COM
authTime=20130422075139Z
startTime=20130422075139Z
endTime=20130422175139Z
renewTill=20130429075139Z
flags: FORWARDABLE;RENEWABLE;INITIAL;PRE-AUTHENT
EType (int): 23
Subject:
    Principal: user1@SUB1.EXAMPLE.COM
    Private Credential: Ticket (hex) = 
.....

Client Principal = user1@SUB1.EXAMPLE.COM
Server Principal = krbtgt/SUB1.EXAMPLE.COM@SUB1.EXAMPLE.COM
Session Key = EncryptionKey: keyType=23 keyBytes (hex dump)=
0000: 2B 8C 97 3C 8E 83 66 F1   6D 58 6C 37 20 0E 1F 53  +..<..f.mXl7 ..S

Forwardable Ticket true
Forwarded Ticket false
Proxiable Ticket false
Proxy Ticket false
Postdated Ticket false
Renewable Ticket true
Initial Ticket true
Auth Time = Mon Apr 22 15:51:39 2013
Start Time = Mon Apr 22 15:51:39 2013
End Time = Tue Apr 23 01:51:39 2013
Renew Till = Mon Apr 29 15:51:39 2013
Client Addresses  Null 

Connecting to LDAP
Config name: krb5.conf
Found ticket for user1@SUB1.EXAMPLE.COM to go to krbtgt/SUB1.EXAMPLE.COM@SUB1.EXAMPLE.COM expiring on Tue Apr 23 01:51:39 2013
Entered Krb5Context.initSecContext with state=STATE_NEW
Service ticket not found in the subject
>>> Credentials acquireServiceCreds: same realm
default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes: 16 3 1.
>>> CksumType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.RsaMd5CksumType
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType
>>> KdcAccessibility: reset
>>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=DDC.SUB1.EXAMPLE.COM UDP:88, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=1554
>>> KDCCommunication: kdc=DDC.SUB1.EXAMPLE.COM UDP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =1, #bytes=1554
>>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=107
>>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=DDC.SUB1.EXAMPLE.COM TCP:88, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=1554
>>> KDCCommunication: kdc=DDC.SUB1.EXAMPLE.COM TCP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =1, #bytes=1554
>>>DEBUG: TCPClient reading 1497 bytes
>>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=1497
>>> KdcAccessibility: remove DDC.SUB1.EXAMPLE.COM
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType
>>> KrbApReq: APOptions are 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.DesCbcMd5EType
Krb5Context setting mySeqNumber to: 1005735013
Krb5Context setting peerSeqNumber to: 0
Created InitSecContextToken:
.....

Krb5Context.unwrap: token=[60 33 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 12 01 02 02 02 01 00 00 ff ff ff ff 94 52 14 5b f6 02 28 1c a4 3c c5 8f 03 9c a2 d6 e5 f6 f1 18 ed 6f 16 ab 07 a0 00 00 04 04 04 04 ]
Krb5Context.unwrap: data=[07 a0 00 00 ]
Krb5Context.wrap: data=[01 01 00 00 ]
Krb5Context.wrap: token=[60 33 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 12 01 02 02 02 01 00 00 ff ff ff ff 2d b6 92 0d d9 51 da aa ef 41 67 33 5c de b3 e6 ce 9a 46 31 a0 a8 0e 27 01 01 00 00 04 04 04 04 ]
Connected
Disconnected
#1: Done
Performing authentication #2
Reading configuration file my_config.txt
kdc: DDC.SUB2.EXAMPLE.COM, realm: SUB2.EXAMPLE.COM
>>>KinitOptions cache name is C:\Users\user1\krb5cc_user1
>> Acquire default native Credentials
>>> Obtained TGT from LSA: Credentials:
client=user1@SUB1.EXAMPLE.COM
server=krbtgt/SUB1.EXAMPLE.COM@SUB1.EXAMPLE.COM
authTime=20130422075139Z
startTime=20130422075139Z
endTime=20130422175139Z
renewTill=20130429075139Z
flags: FORWARDABLE;RENEWABLE;INITIAL;PRE-AUTHENT
EType (int): 23
Subject:
    Principal: user1@SUB1.EXAMPLE.COM
    Private Credential: Ticket (hex) = 
.....

Client Principal = user1@SUB1.EXAMPLE.COM
Server Principal = krbtgt/SUB1.EXAMPLE.COM@SUB1.EXAMPLE.COM
Session Key = EncryptionKey: keyType=23 keyBytes (hex dump)=
0000: 2B 8C 97 3C 8E 83 66 F1   6D 58 6C 37 20 0E 1F 53  +..<..f.mXl7 ..S

Forwardable Ticket true
Forwarded Ticket false
Proxiable Ticket false
Proxy Ticket false
Postdated Ticket false
Renewable Ticket true
Initial Ticket true
Auth Time = Mon Apr 22 15:51:39 2013
Start Time = Mon Apr 22 15:51:39 2013
End Time = Tue Apr 23 01:51:39 2013
Renew Till = Mon Apr 29 15:51:39 2013
Client Addresses  Null 

Connecting to LDAP
Found ticket for user1@SUB1.EXAMPLE.COM to go to krbtgt/SUB1.EXAMPLE.COM@SUB1.EXAMPLE.COM expiring on Tue Apr 23 01:51:39 2013
Entered Krb5Context.initSecContext with state=STATE_NEW
Service ticket not found in the subject
>>> Credentials acquireServiceCreds: same realm
default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes: 16 3 1.
>>> CksumType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.RsaMd5CksumType
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType
>>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=DDC.SUB1.EXAMPLE.COM UDP:88, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=1554
>>> KDCCommunication: kdc=DDC.SUB1.EXAMPLE.COM UDP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =1, #bytes=1554
>>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=107
>>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=DDC.SUB1.EXAMPLE.COM TCP:88, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=1554
>>> KDCCommunication: kdc=DDC.SUB1.EXAMPLE.COM TCP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =1, #bytes=1554
>>>DEBUG: TCPClient reading 1482 bytes
>>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=1482
>>> KdcAccessibility: remove DDC.SUB1.EXAMPLE.COM
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType
KrbException: Message stream modified (41)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbKdcRep.check(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsRep.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsReq.getReply(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsReq.sendAndGetCreds(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.CredentialsUtil.serviceCreds(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.CredentialsUtil.acquireServiceCreds(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.krb5.Credentials.acquireServiceCreds(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.initSecContext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.sasl.LdapSasl.saslBind(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at gssapitest.JndiAction.performJndiOperation(myTest.java:603)
    at gssapitest.JndiAction.run(myTest.java:577)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
    at gssapitest.myTest.Do(myTest.java:59)
    at gssapitest.myTest.main(myTest.java:513)
javax.naming.AuthenticationException: GSSAPI [Root exception is javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Message stream modified (41))]]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.sasl.LdapSasl.saslBind(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at gssapitest.JndiAction.performJndiOperation(myTest.java:603)
    at gssapitest.JndiAction.run(myTest.java:577)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
    at gssapitest.myTest.Do(myTest.java:59)
    at gssapitest.myTest.main(myTest.java:513)
Caused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Message stream modified (41))]
    at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(Unknown Source)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Message stream modified (41))
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.initSecContext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(Unknown Source)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: KrbException: Message stream modified (41)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbKdcRep.check(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsRep.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsReq.getReply(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsReq.sendAndGetCreds(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.CredentialsUtil.serviceCreds(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.CredentialsUtil.acquireServiceCreds(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.krb5.Credentials.acquireServiceCreds(Unknown Source)
    ... 22 more
FAILED
```

What can I do? Am I doings something wrongs?

Answer (score 9):

Thanks for this! Just for reference, uppercase of the realm (ie. the realm should be 100% correct and in uppercase) is very important to avoid "Exception: krb_error 41 Message stream modified (41) ".

Here's an example of correct notation:

```
[libdefaults] 
default_realm = EXAMPLE.COM

[realms] 
EXAMPLE.COM = { 
kdc = domaincontroller.example.com
admin_server = domaincontroller.example.com
default_domain = EXAMPLE.COM
} 

[domain_realm] 
.example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
```

Regards,

Nika.

Comment: Timely fix - this was exactly what was wrong about my config.  Not an intuitive error at all, but putting the domain to upper case fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

NTLM != Kerberos. Java SASL does not support NTLM. Configure Kerberos properly and it'll work.

Comment: I think I configured it properly. I posted my code and my configurations, I'll be happy if you can help understanding what's wrong. Thanks.

Comment: What do you expect to use? NTLM or Kerberos?

Comment: 1. Remove all `System.setProperty` from your app and supply them with `-D` at start time. 2. Provide sample hostnames (SPNs) and UPNs where your are trying to connect. We need to check the entire path. Cross-realm in a forest not a problem with JGSS. This works here with a charm. You might want to ease the pain for boiler-plate from by using this [library](http://dirctxsrc.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I cannot remove the System.setProperty because currently I'm using these in order to work with different realms. Without those, I will not be able to work with different subdomains even if I'll restart my application. Unfortunately, I cannot perform major changes like using a different library...

Comment: Why? All realms are specified in the `krb.conf`. These is no need to duplicate those. SPNs: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc228113.aspx).

Comment: Tried without the setProperty: The application does not work at all when working with the forign domain (not the domain the bind user is connected to). If I'll specify the default domain in the krb5 file, the application will work only with that domain and no with others. I guess I have to use the setPropery statements.

Comment: No, you don't your `krb5.conf` is incorrect. You still have failed to provide the information I have asked for. Otherwise I am not able to help you.

Comment: There is no need to publish them 1:1. I am fully satisfied if you obfuscate them as long as the struncture remains the same.

Comment: But I'm not using the SPN's. My code and my config is written above together with the output with krb.debug=true - I'm just using the realm and kdc...

Comment: Yes, you are using them because SPNs, DNS names and realms are closely related and you DO have a realm problem.

Comment: Yes, it does seem like a realm problem. So please, explain me how to get those SPN's from my code / configurations and I'll provide it.

Comment: I was able to reprocude this issue with Windows 7 and Windows Server 2003 and 2008 KDCs. You are missing a few `[domain_realm]` entries. At it resolved here. It should look like [this](http://pastebin.com/JmkqnWpF).