# Java/Tomcat app with Kerberos

Tags: java, tomcat, kerberos

I'm a Kerberos newbie and I'm trying to configure a Java/Tomcat app to talk to a database using Kerberos for authentication. I'm getting stack trace that it's not able to connect and that there are no valid credentials but I can't tell what the problem is.

Here's my krb5.conf...

```
[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
 default_keytab_name = FILE:C:\Users\QZAJ\Documents\repos\secure.qzaj\qzaj.keytab
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 renew_lifetime = 7d
 forwardable = true
 rdns = false
# default_realm = WINDOWSKDCDOMAIN
 default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}

[realms]
WINDOWSKDCDOMAIN = {
kdc = DEVDC01.DEV.MYDOMAIN.COM :88
}

[domain_realm]
#.MYDOMAIN.com = WINDOWSKDCDOMAIN
#MYDOMAIN.com = WINDOWSKDCDOMAIN
```

And my jaas.conf...

```
com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.initiate {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    useKeyTab=true
    doNotPrompt=true
    keyTab="C:\Users\QZAJ\Documents\repos\secure.qzaj\qzaj.keytab"
    principal="QZAJ@MYDOMAIN.NET"
    debug=true
};
com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.accept {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    useKeyTab=true
    doNotPrompt=true
    keyTab="C:\Users\QZAJ\Documents\repos\secure.qzaj\qzaj.keytab"
    principal="QZAJ@MYDOMAIN.NET"
    debug=true
};
```

My keytab file...

```
MYDOMAIN.NET QZAJ   X\e  �...
MYDOMAIN.NET QZAJ   X\e   �...
```

And the error/stack trace when I run it...

```
>>>KinitOptions cache name is C:\Users\QZAJ\krb5cc_qzaj
>> Acquire default native Credentials
Using builtin default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 17 16 23.
>>> Obtained TGT from LSA: Credentials:
      client=QZAJ@MYDOMAIN.NET
      server=krbtgt/MYDOMAIN.NET@MYDOMAIN.NET
    authTime=20161228220909Z
   startTime=20161228220909Z
     endTime=20161229073249Z
   renewTill=20170104213249Z
       flags=FORWARDABLE;RENEWABLE;PRE-AUTHENT
EType (skey)=17
   (tkt key)=18
Found ticket for QZAJ@MYDOMAIN.NET to go to krbtgt/MYDOMAIN.NET@MYDOMAIN.NET expiring on Wed Dec 28 23:32:49 PST 2016
Entered Krb5Context.initSecContext with state=STATE_NEW
Service ticket not found in the subject
>>> Credentials acquireServiceCreds: same realm
Using builtin default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes
default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes: 17 16 23.
>>> CksumType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.RsaMd5CksumType
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes128CtsHmacSha1EType
getKDCFromDNS using UDP
>>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=a0319dc17.MYDOMAIN.net. TCP:88, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=2108
>>> KDCCommunication: kdc=a0319dc17.MYDOMAIN.net. TCP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =1, #bytes=2108
>>>DEBUG: TCPClient reading 2050 bytes
>>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=2050
>>> KdcAccessibility: remove a0319dc17.MYDOMAIN.net.:88
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes128CtsHmacSha1EType
KrbException: Message stream modified (41)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbKdcRep.check(KrbKdcRep.java:50)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsRep.<init>(KrbTgsRep.java:87)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsReq.getReply(KrbTgsReq.java:259)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsReq.sendAndGetCreds(KrbTgsReq.java:270)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.CredentialsUtil.serviceCreds(CredentialsUtil.java:302)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.CredentialsUtil.acquireServiceCreds(CredentialsUtil.java:120)
    at sun.security.krb5.Credentials.acquireServiceCreds(Credentials.java:458)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.initSecContext(Krb5Context.java:693)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:248)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.KerbAuthentication.intAuthHandShake(KerbAuthentication.java:226)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.KerbAuthentication.GenerateClientContext(KerbAuthentication.java:314)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:4116)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3188)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$100(SQLServerConnection.java:61)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3151)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7535)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2438)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1973)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1616)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1447)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:788)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1187)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    ...
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Integrated authentication failed. ClientConnectionId:a27a8ca0-5c80-4f88-9908-49650040a303
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:2392)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.KerbAuthentication.intAuthHandShake(KerbAuthentication.java:247)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.KerbAuthentication.GenerateClientContext(KerbAuthentication.java:314)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:4116)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3188)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$100(SQLServerConnection.java:61)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3151)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7535)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2438)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1973)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1616)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1447)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:788)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1187)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    ...
Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Message stream modified (41))
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.initSecContext(Krb5Context.java:770)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:248)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.KerbAuthentication.intAuthHandShake(KerbAuthentication.java:226)
    ...
Caused by: KrbException: Message stream modified (41)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbKdcRep.check(KrbKdcRep.java:50)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsRep.<init>(KrbTgsRep.java:87)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsReq.getReply(KrbTgsReq.java:259)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsReq.sendAndGetCreds(KrbTgsReq.java:270)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.CredentialsUtil.serviceCreds(CredentialsUtil.java:302)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.CredentialsUtil.acquireServiceCreds(CredentialsUtil.java:120)
    at sun.security.krb5.Credentials.acquireServiceCreds(Credentials.java:458)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.initSecContext(Krb5Context.java:693)
    ...
```

I don't understand where it's going wrong. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Important Kerberos elements do not match up between your configuration files.  That needs to be cleaned up.  And there is no telling what is actually inside your keytab.  Using a good editor like Notepad++, can you right-click on your qzaj.keytab file and then edit your question by pasting the keytab contents to the bottom of your question?   The secret key inside is encrypted so that will appear as gibberish, but I want to see how the SPN is represented inside of it in order to help solve this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GSSException: Message stream modified (41)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15932361/gssexception-message-stream-modified-41)

Comment: Hello @T-Heron, I added the keytab file right below the jaas.config.

Comment: Thanks for adding that in.  I see your edit.  In your keytab, you have a MYDOMAIN.NET realm defined for a service QZAJ, but in krb5.conf you have realm defined as WINDOWSKDCDOMAIN.  In jass.conf you have MYDOMAIN.NET.  So what is up with WINDOWSKDCDOMAIN in krb5.conf??

Comment: Hi @KarthikeyanVaithilingam , I saw that post. Unfortunately it did not help.

Comment: Problem Solved. Thank you @T-Heron for pointing me in the right direction. I changed my realm to DEV.MYDOMAIN.COM and updated the default_realm and domain_realm mappings to point to it and everything just started working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `renew_lifetime` 
I discovered this solution through trial and error, and the only backing up material I've found online is this: 
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-yarn-dev/201909.mbox/%3CCAKRKJ1O3yrYKDZ=WhU=i6A+zqxFnUidxvwQzNCTW0mnEv2WFPA@mail.gmail.com%3E